# Binance crypto alerting bot by python

Tags: python, cryptography, bots, binance

this is my first post.
I'm making a bot that can gmail me if the price of btc fluctuate dramatically. However, I don't know how to make python to update infinitely to get the latest price from Binance(a crypto exchange) without for loop? Thank you.

```
from binance.client import Client
import sys

def btcPriceDetect():
    client = Client("api key","api secret",{"verify": False, "timeout": 20})

    tickers = client.get_ticker(symbol='BTCUSDT', requests_params={'timeout': 5})

    print(tickers['lastPrice'])


for i in range(sys.maxsize**10):
    btcPriceDetect()
```

Comment: I feel like it would better to change the architecture to a "one-shot" script, that checks your stuff once, and sends the email. Call that via a cronjob every 1 minute or so. With a for loop like that, it will likely run thousands of times per minute.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write an infinite loop, but I think the most straightforward is using `while True:`, for example:

```
import time

while True:
    btcPriceDetect()
    time.sleep(60) # suspend thread for one minute
```